# Index in hstore with no predictable key

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, hstore

Lets say I have a blog database where posts table stores tags in hstore.
Keys represent tag ids and values are tag names.

ex : `1=>'Test', 56=>'SQL', 42=>'Java'`

I want to have optimized selects on posts with tag filter.
How and what type of select should I create on tags column in order to optimize this query

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE tags?'4'
```

The issue is that I don't have predictable key names on order to create index based on their value.

Would it be a good solution to create gist index on column?
And how I can make it to treat key as an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A GIN index is probably the better choice:

```
CREATE INDEX posts_tags_idx ON posts USING gin (tags);
```

That works for *all* keys.
You could further optimize the index if queries are only for a specific key with a [partial index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-partial.html):

```
CREATE INDEX posts_tags_idx ON posts USING gin (tags -> '4')) WHERE x ? '4';
```

[`hstore ? text` ...  does hstore contain key?](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/hstore.html#HSTORE-OP-TABLE)

But that doesn't seem to be an option for you.

`hstore` stores `text` only, not `integer`. [Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/hstore.html)

> Keys and values are simply text strings.