# A table with thousands of records, and each record hundreds of attributes with PostgreSQL?

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, database-design

I am currently running PostgreSQL and I have a requirement of creating a table called Template.

The users will be able to create lots of templates, and each template will have hundreds of attributes (more will be added in the future). So the schema of which attributes will be in the table is dynamic. More will be added.

For the querying, I should be able to say, give me all the templates which attribute A is bigger than 5, attribute B is false, attribute D is "good",..

So, there will be a lot of WHERE X AND Y AND Z.

I am considering using MongoDB or some NoSQL engine to store these resources as the schema can vary (at least the attributes that I will store for the templates), but I am not sure if that is a good point enough.

So my question is: Does it make sense to use MongoDB for the above reason?

Comment: you might consider the json (or jsonb) datatype.  it makes a dynamic store easy.  i have several tables in my database with columns of type json.  I can stick anything in those columns.  also, with the new jsonb type, the penalties for such a behavior are becoming less severe :-)  you can put an index on it, making searching efficient (i think a gin index is the one to use).

Comment: I would use a `hstore` column to store those attributes. It can be indexed and questions like "*give me all the templates which attribute A is bigger than 5*" can be resolved *very* efficiently. Much faster than using JSON (at least for now - this will somewhat change with the upcoming 9.4)

Comment: What @a_horse said. Plus you can index an `hstore` (or `json` / `jsonb`) column with a GIN index or use a functional index targeting only selected fields of the column. [More in this related answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22183372/index-in-hstore-with-no-predictable-key/22184085#22184085)

Comment: Guys, I need to fetch those attributes heavily. I mean, I will have a lots of queries fetching conditions on those attributes. According to the docs ``This can be useful in various scenarios, such as rows with many attributes that are rarely examined, or semi-structured data`` But mine will be not rarely examined, but they will be examined a lot. Could you elaborate in an answer so I can accept?